# Docker + NodeJS: Cannot Find package.json in directory

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I am building out a ReactJS/Node.JS application in Docker. I am getting the following error where my package.json is never found:

```
server_1    | 
server_1    | > stocklookback@1.0.0 dev /code/app/server
server_1    | > concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"
server_1    | 
server_1    | [1] 
server_1    | [1] > stocklookback@1.0.0 client /code/app/server
server_1    | [1] > npm start
server_1    | [1] 
server_1    | [0] 
server_1    | [0] > stocklookback@1.0.0 server /code/app/server
server_1    | [0] > nodemon index.js
server_1    | [0] 
client_1    | npm ERR! path /code/app/client/package.json
client_1    | npm ERR! code ENOENT
client_1    | npm ERR! errno -2
client_1    | npm ERR! syscall open
client_1    | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/code/app/client/package.json'
client_1    | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
client_1    | npm ERR! enoent 
client_1    | 
client_1    | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
client_1    | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-08-06T13_49_58_383Z-debug.log
server_1    | [1] 
server_1    | [1] > stocklookback@1.0.0 start /code/app/server
server_1    | [1] > node index.js
server_1    | [1] 
server_1    | [0] [nodemon] 1.19.1
server_1    | [0] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
server_1    | [0] [nodemon] watching: *.*
server_1    | [0] [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
stocklookback_client_1 exited with code 254
```

My Dockerfile for the client is:

```
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /code/app/client
WORKDIR /code/app/client/

COPY package.json /code/app/client/
COPY package-lock.json /code/app/client/

RUN npm install

COPY . /code/app/client/

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

The package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

And the docker-compose.yml is

```
version: '3.3'

volumes:
  postgres_database :
     external: false

services:

##########################
# Setup node container
##########################

 server:
   build: ./server
   expose:
     - ${APP_SERVER_PORT}
   environment:
     API_HOST: ${API_HOST}
     APP_SERVER_PORT: ${APP_SERVER_PORT}
   ports:
     - ${APP_SERVER_PORT}:${APP_SERVER_PORT}
   volumes:
     - ./server:/code/app/server/src
   command: npm run dev

##########################
# Setup client container
##########################

 client:
   build: ./client
   environment: 
     - REACT_APP_PORT=${REACT_APP_PORT}
   expose:
     - ${REACT_APP_PORT}
   ports:
     - ${REACT_APP_PORT}:${REACT_APP_PORT}
   volumes:
     - ./client/src:/code/app/client/
     - ./client/public:/code/app/client/public
   links:
     - server
   command: npm start
```

The file structure is like so:

[image]

Why is my package.json not being copied over?

Comment: A couple of debugging tips I often use:  `RUN pwd` and  `RUN ls` before your _npm install_ command.  This will help you see what got copied in.  Check your .dockerignore file too maybe?

Comment: set `WORKDIR /code/app/client/` before npm start